# What do network interfaces mean in three-node architecture with OpenStack Networking?

Tags: networking, openstack

I am installing openstack by a guide. When it comes to networking interfaces setting, I just can't understand this 
[openstack networking diagram](http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-networking-neutron.html)

I am confused what management, instance tunnels, and external mean.

My network interface settings:

```
 Controller node: 
    eth0:  #I suppose for management
         IP:      192.168.1.39 
         netmask: 255.255.255.0 

 Network node:
    eth0:   #I suppose for management
         IP:      192.168.1.38 
         netmask: 255.255.255.0
    eth1:   #I suppose it is for Instance tunnels
         IP: #I have no idea what address should I assign here???
    eth2:  #I suppose it is external interface
         auto eth2
              iface eth2 inet manual
              up ip link set dev $IFACE up
              down ip link set dev $IFACE down

Compute node:
    eth0:  #I suppose for management
         IP:      192.168.1.32 
         netmask: 255.255.255.0 
    eth1:   #I suppose it is for Instance tunnels
         IP: #I have no idea what address should I assign here???
```

My knowledge is not enough to handle these, could anyone point out what material I should refer to? And I want to know the meaning of management, instance tunnels, external, and how can I config for those network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit poor and assumes a bit of knowledge.

Anyway, it all depends on the setup.  Typically there are a number of logical networks.

Are you installing using the manual steps or are you using an installer such as RDO, as you may find the networking models slightly different ?

A typical setup would have something like this.

Management / API - this gives you ssh access onto the box, and exposes the service APIs so that clients can remotely interface with the cloud.

Internal - communication between services in a multi node setup.  On test setups this is often collapsed into management.

Private / instance - in Openstack your tenants can create virtual networks.  There are a number of ways to do this but GRE it VXLAN is fairly popular.  This acts as an encapsulation layer running over the top of your l2 network.

External then is usually a routable ip, and is either a network that gives direct access to your VMs, or is a range that is used for your floating IPs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I understand for now is that instance tunnel network is another network configured on top of my regular network. Can I just set eth1 of instance tunnel network IP address the same as eth0 of management network?

Answer (score 0):

tunnel network is for communication which is not important for controller or other nodes.

For ex. if you have two compute node. both have VM with 10.10.10.5/16 and 10.10.1.27/16. if both want to communication, then router or switch for both is hosted on network node. so VM hosted under openstack cloud, they don't need to communicate with controller, so this data travels through tunnel network between compute node and network node.